# How many rows can a HDF5 dataset have?

Tags: database, hdf5

So I've been wondering, for how long I could save high-frequency data into a hdf5 dataset.

I came across this website:
[HDF5 Limits](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/limits.html)

This either does not answer my question or I am missing some basic understanding. 
So the dimensions are the columns in a dataset? What is a value of a dimension? Is it the values it can contain? So unsigned 64 bit would be 2^64 values?

I truly appreciate helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically tabular data is stored in HDF5 as a one-dimensional dataset with a compound type.  I.e. each field in your dataset becomes an element of the type.  So the maximum length of the table would be 2^64.